# Matplotlib : Plotting interpolate-d part of the data with different line/marker/color

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I would like to be able to plot the part of the data which had been interpolate-d(circled in red) with a different FMT.

My current idea was to plot 2 line, original and only the interpolate-d part of the data, with different FMT to differentiate the interpolate part making it seems as a singular line. But I'm having trouble extracting the data that have been interpolate-d and I'm not sure if my idea is currently viable or is there a simpler alternative to accomplish it.

### original data

```
                         Phoenix  Chicago
datetime                             
2012-10-02 10:00:00     30.0     63.0
2012-10-02 11:00:00     30.0     63.0
2012-10-02 12:00:00     31.0     62.0
2012-10-02 13:00:00     31.0     62.0
2012-10-02 14:00:00     32.0     62.0
2012-10-02 15:00:00     17.0     51.0
2012-10-02 16:00:00     28.0      NaN
2012-10-02 17:00:00      NaN      NaN
2012-10-02 18:00:00      9.0     42.0
2012-10-02 19:00:00      NaN      NaN
2012-10-02 20:00:00     13.0      NaN
2012-10-02 21:00:00      NaN      NaN
2012-10-02 22:00:00      7.0     48.0
2012-10-02 23:00:00      6.0     48.0
```

```
plt.plot(df[['Phoenix','Chicago']], marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

### After interpolate

```
                     Phoenix  Chicago
datetime                             
2012-10-02 10:00:00     30.0     63.0
2012-10-02 11:00:00     30.0     63.0
2012-10-02 12:00:00     31.0     62.0
2012-10-02 13:00:00     31.0     62.0
2012-10-02 14:00:00     32.0     62.0
2012-10-02 15:00:00     17.0     51.0
2012-10-02 16:00:00     28.0     48.0
2012-10-02 17:00:00     18.5     45.0
2012-10-02 18:00:00      9.0     42.0
2012-10-02 19:00:00     11.0     43.5
2012-10-02 20:00:00     13.0     45.0
2012-10-02 21:00:00     10.0     46.5
2012-10-02 22:00:00      7.0     48.0
2012-10-02 23:00:00      6.0     48.0
```

```
df.interpolate(inplace = True)
plt.plot(df[['Phoenix','Chicago']], marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Rough Idea of what i'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: you can use pandas method "interpolate" for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since matplotlib omits missing data (which is usually considered a problem), we can use this fact here and simply plot the original data over the interpolated data:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#recreate your data
from io import StringIO
data = """datetime                    Phoenix  Chicago                           
2012-10-02 10:00:00     30.0     63.0
2012-10-02 11:00:00     30.0     63.0
2012-10-02 12:00:00     31.0     62.0
2012-10-02 13:00:00     31.0     62.0
2012-10-02 14:00:00     32.0     62.0
2012-10-02 15:00:00     17.0     51.0
2012-10-02 16:00:00     28.0      NaN
2012-10-02 17:00:00      NaN      NaN
2012-10-02 18:00:00      9.0     42.0
2012-10-02 19:00:00      NaN      NaN
2012-10-02 20:00:00     13.0      NaN
2012-10-02 21:00:00      NaN      NaN
2012-10-02 22:00:00      7.0     48.0
2012-10-02 23:00:00      6.0     48.0"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep = "\s{2,}", engine="python", parse_dates=["datetime"], na_values = "NaN")
df = df.set_index("datetime")

#interpolate and plot the interpolated data with transparency and dashed lines
dfint = df.interpolate()
plt.plot(dfint[['Phoenix','Chicago']], marker = 'o', alpha=0.5, ls="--")
#reset color cycle, so that the colors match
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)
#plot again with missing data
plt.plot(df[['Phoenix','Chicago']], marker = 'o')
plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.interpolate()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) method:

```py
plt.plot(df[['Phoenix','Chicago']].interpolate(), marker = 'o')
```

[image: plot]

EDIT (after editing the question):

If you want to plot both interpolated version and not interpolated one, you can simply plot the not interpolated one on top of it:

```py
plt.plot(df[['Phoenix','Chicago']].interpolate(), marker = 'x', ls="--")
plt.plot(df[['Phoenix','Chicago']].interpolate(), marker = 'o')
```

[image: 2nd plot]

PS. Data for reproduction:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": pd.period_range(start='2012-10-02 10:00:00', end='2012-10-02 23:00:00', freq='H').to_timestamp(),
                   "Phoenix": [30., 30., 31., 31., 32., 17., 28., np.nan, 9., np.nan, 13., np.nan, 7., 6.],
                   "Chicago": [63., 63., 62., 62., 62., 51., np.nan, np.nan, 42., np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 48., 48.]})\
                       .set_index("datetime")
```